# What is the best enchantments for PvP?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

What are the best enchantments for minecraft that would prove to be the most beneficial  for pvp combat?By best I mean,easier to take down players and protect me more all while not overdoing it with the enchantments on other items.
Looking for enchantments for:
Axe
Trident
Sword

Comment: Hmmm... Not sure if good or bad question o.O

Comment: This would be a good subjective question.  Answerers, ensure to not only answer which enchantments you would use, but also *why* you would use them.

Answer (score 2):

Screw helmet and boots, they aren't needed. As for chest plate and leggings: Protection 4 and Projectile Protection 3-4. This will make snipers deal hardly any damage at all and melee deal low damage.

As for your weapon, if your server has mcmmo use a axe. Anyways:

Sword: Fire Aspect 2, Knockback 2, Sharpness 5
Axe: Fire Aspect 2, Sharpness 5.

All these need a anvil and most need enchanted books so it isn't cheap.

This is the best PvP gear possible. The shoes and hat won't do anything against attacks on top of all that Protection 4 – two pieces is maxed out.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with perfection 4 and projectile protection 4 but you need fire protection or you will be set on fire and die. And with the updates you want to have thorns on it to

Answer (score 0):

Use full Protection IV with a Fire Protection IV helmet and a Sharpness II, Fire Aspect II sword.

Comment: Full Protection is redundant, the bonus is capped.

Answer (score 0):

You should have 2x Prot. IV and 1x Fire Prot. IV and 1x Projectile Prot. IV. As for the bow, best would be a power 5 flame 1 punch 2 bow. If you are going for long battles, unbreaking 3 on your bow would be a nice thing to have. Getting infinity on this already heavily enchanted bow would be very likely too expensive(for the anvil), so dont go for it. If you are more of a melee attacker, then you should not have the knockback enchantment on your sword as you would let the enemy have more retreat time. Knockback 2 is excellent for an archer. Also, if you are fighting in water, respiration 3 enchantment on helmet may become handy.

Answer (score -1):

The best gear is full diamond with protection IV on each, but with feather falling on the boots. The sword needs Sharp V and Fireaspect I or II. Potions would help a lot and the enchanting is easy 'cause all you have to do is put a level 1 on the book and use anvil to max them out. I think anvils are too cheap XD